# Where does type declaration in programming languages come from?

Tags: types, programming-languages

When we define a function in C/C++, we type something like

```
int add(int a, int b){
    return a+b;
}
```

However, the actual thing we do in the function is to get the sum of two summable things and return its value. In many early-created programming languages like Algol, C, pascal, you should declare the type of a variable before do some operations on it. Also, this is required in quite a lot of mainstream languages such as Java, C#(although it has keywords like "var").

In many dynamic programming languages like Python, we rewrite the previous function to:

```
def add(a,b):
    return a+b
```

without "type identifier" of the function and arguments. What I am thinking about is that, compared with languages like C/C++, the Python version seems to be closer to the primitive idea in a programmer's mind: just encapsulate the behavior of adding two numbers together and return the sum.

On the other hand, in the practice, these type declarations help me a lot with reducing the mistake, for example, I won't pass a string to the "add" function if i just want a sum of two numbers. If I pass two strings, the compiler will treat this as an error. Type declaration seems to be protection of the code in this example.

But what makes me confused is that, why does so many early-created languages require a type declaration for a variable? Why did most languages with type declaration come earlier and the most languages with simpler version of syntax comes later in the history?

I know we cannot tell which approach is "better" and they are both Turing-complete, but I'm just curious that why did not the early language creators chose more intuitive and simlpler syntax which  is focus on the implementation of a function 100%, but chose to add type identifier as a requied part of the language(Question 1)? Also, at early time, people have very obscure impression of what code should look like, so I guess the idea of type identifier **must** come from somewhere. My second question is that where does the idea of type declaration come from(math? practice? or somewhere else?)? I think I will have a better understanding of "type" if I know the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arguably, the notion of data type existed in programming languages from the get go. The very first languages where machine languages, and even for those it can be relevant wether you, say, add integers or add floats. The type distinction is made by using different instructions, though.

The first more high-level language was Fortran (mid 1950s). Fortran distinguished variable types, but instead of doing it based on type declarations, it did it based on variable names. For example, variables i,j k etc would be integers, and p, q, r floats (IIRC). That allows using the same convenient notation for e.g. addition, no matter what the type is.

Obviously, that's a pretty hacky idea, and does not scale to any more interesting type system. So the next generation of languages, notably Algol (late 1950s), made that more explicit, and introduced a syntax for types.

With languages becoming more high-level and supporting more interesting kinds of data, type systems also became more interesting. At some point (around 1970) it was realised that types in programming languages actually are very closely related to a notion of types already known from math: namely, in typed lambda calculus, invented in the 1930s. In fact, it was realised that the relation between computational logic and programming languages is actually an extremely close one on all levels, and that programming languages can be explained as variants of lambda calculi, which is what most modern programming language theory (and design) does.

Untyped (or so-called "dynamically typed", in a notable abuse of terminology) programming languages are also quite old. The first one was Lisp (late 1950s), which in fact already took inspiration from untyped lambda calculus. However, this kind of languages did not become popular until much later. The reason is that they require significantly more costly machinery in the runtime systems, which wasn't affordable in the earlier days of computing, and often still aren't today. (The recent hype about such languages seems to ebb away a little these days, as it is (re)discovered that this form of development does not scale well -- witnessed by all the type systems that are now being invented for these languages: Typed Scheme, TypeScript, MyPy, Hack, etc.)

Another inspiration that programming languages partially took from logic btw is type inference. Even when typed lambda calculi where originally invented, there were already two forms: explicitly typed and implicitly typed. The functional language ML was the first to adopt a similar idea to programming (late 1970s): an ML program is fully type-checked without writing a single type declaration. More recently, this idea has arrived in mainstream languages, though usually in far more limited ways.

That is to point out that the difference between typed and untyped is not necessarily tied to syntax and the presence of type declarations -- a language can be ("statically") typed and not require type declarations.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I'm curious about. By the way, we often see notations defining functions in math like f:R^2->R, is this has some relation with the type declaration in programming?

Comment: @sorrow17, well, yes, type theory (in computational logic) was invented as a foundational theory for math, just like set theory, so it naturally borrowed notation. From there it probably found its way into programming languages, e.g., in lambda calculus you'd write `f : R × R → R`, and in ML `f : real * real -> real` as type annotations.

Answer (score 1):

Andreas' excellent history does not address the first part of the question. Data types existed in programming languages from early on, but the question being asked is why type declarations were required.

The reason is memory capacity. Programs, including compilers, had to run with very limited amounts of memory at that time. This has two direct consequences:

- Programmers couldn't afford to use a one-size-fits-all approach to representing data, because it uses memory inefficiently; they wanted to specialize the representation of their data for different types so that more data could fit in memory at one time.
- Compilers could not fit entire programs in memory at one time, so they needed to be able to compile parts of it separately, and link them later. To compile one part, it is in general necessary to know how data is represented in other parts.

The type declarations, in C at least, provided a solution to both of these problems.

Comment: Good answer, especially the "link" part. Thanks!